# Border Radius only rounding the top of a div?

Tags: html, css

Applying border-radius property on a div with a border only applies it to the top corners. Why is that?

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/07tqbo56/1/

```css
.asd {
  margin-top: 35px; 
  width: 123px;
  border-top-style: solid; 
  border-top-color: #1163b9; 
  border-top-width: 70px; 
  border-radius: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="asd"></div>
```

[image]

This is how it looks like on Firefox 72, Ubuntu 19.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because your other `border` properties are only being applied to the top border, for example, `border-top-style` needs to be just `border-style`.

When only one border is `solid`, some browsers apply `border-radius` to just that border, while others still apply it to all borders.

```css
.asd {
  margin-top: 35px; 
  width: 123px;
  border-style: solid; 
  border-color: #1163b9; 
  border-width: 70px; 
  border-radius: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="asd"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Not only in FireFox, it will look like that in all browsers,

Are you trying to do like this?

Just deleted the "Top" in `border-style, -color and -width`.
"Top" will do the changes only on the top of the design.

```css
.asd {
  margin: 35px; 
  width: 123px;
  border-style: solid; 
  border-color: #1163b9; 
  border-width: 70px; 
  border-radius: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="asd"></div>
```

I hope this would have solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Define CSS like this

```css
.asd {
  margin-top: 35px; 
  width: 123px;
  border: 70px solid #1163b9;
  border-radius: 70px
}
```

```html
<div class="asd"></div>
```